# Go lang connect to Oracle 9i (using go-oci8)

Tags: oracle, go, oracle9i

I have a 32 bit Oracle DB (version 9i - 9.2.0.7.0), a 64 bit Mac and am trying to connect to it using [go-oci8](https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8) with Go Lang (version go1.11.1 darwin/amd64).

I used SQL-Developer [4.0.2](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-downloads-403-2292439.html) to successfully connect to the DB and then enabled InstantClient connection through it using [this](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/01/oracle-sql-developer-4-and-the-oracle-client/) tutorial. So I've got things running from the Oracle Client's side.

I'm using InstantClient Version 11.2.0.4.0 (32-bit) for MacOS (basic and SDK), I've used mainly [this](https://gocodecloud.com/blog/2016/08/09/accessing-an-oracle-db-in-go/) tutorial almost successfully. After everything, the error I'm getting is:

`github.com/mattn/go-oci8 ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/myusername/Downloads/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/myusername/Downloads/instantclient_11_2/libclntsh.dylib Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:`

And then a long stack of symbols. Basically the Go oci8 library is trying to use C (which is 64 bit) and tries to build 64 bit files, which will then be used by Go. If I try with the 64 bit version of InstantClient, I have no problems, but I get a "driver: bad connection" error which is because 64bit won't work to connect some reason.

I have no idea what to do to resole this issue - can I somehow force the build of 32 bit files while using `go get -u -v github.com/mattn/go-oci8`? Or somehow make the 64 bit InstantClient version connect to the old 32 bit Oracle DB?

Any kind of help on how to get this running would be much appreciated.

Edit: I've tried 10.2 Oracle Client, but I can't connect it with go-oci8 (I'm assuming it doesn't support it). The error I get is `../github.com/mattn/go-oci8/oci8.go:113:25: could not determine kind of name for C.OCI_SYSASM`

**Final edit for people who have the same problem** (coming on to a very old Oracle Database) - you can't interface with the readily provided solutions using Go. The libraries listed to work with Oracle operate with Client versions 11.2 and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture of the Oracle Client have to match so architecture of your application. I.e. if your Go Lang is 64-bit then the Oracle Client have to be also 64-bit. It does not matter whether the database is 32 or 64-bit.

I think the main problem is, you cannot connect with an Oracle 11.2 Client to a (20 years old!) Oracle 9i database.

Check [Client / Server Interoperability Support Matrix for Different Oracle Versions (Doc ID 207303.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=138710094513777&id=207303.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=yoihn9em0_4) for details.

It says:

> For connections between 10.2 (or higher) and 9.2 the 9.2 end MUST be
>   at 9.2.0.4 or higher. Connections between 10.2 (or higher) and
>   9.2.0.1, 9.2.0.2 or 9.2.0.3 have never been supported.

You did not tell us which version of "Oracle 9i" your ar using.

Comment: The version is 9.2.0.7 . I've since tried using the 64 bit version of 11.2 and I keep getting a ```Error connecting to the database: driver: bad connection``` so I'm assuming that I'll need to go lower than 11.2 and try out 10.2 and pray it works.

Comment: What about a database upgrade?

Comment: This is in the works, but is the long-term solution. I was hoping for a quick way to engage with it, but I'll have to turn to an older language like PHP or Python. After your comment and my final digging in the evening, I believe that no Go package supports Oracle 10.2 Client version.

Thank you for the help and reading through my struggles.